# Shiny sliderInput not working in Chrome browser

Tags: google-chrome, slider, shiny

I updated from Shiny 0.10 to 0.11 and my sliders stopped working, but only in Chrome - Firefox works without any problem. The slider appears without a problem, but I cannot move it at all. If it's relevant, the `sliderInput` is within a `renderUI` in the server.R file.

`sliderInput("test","Test",min=0,max=100,value=50,step=5,post="%")`

Comment: i had the same issue... and can't figure out why it does not work the `slierInput` is within a `fluidpage`

Comment: just posted the fix as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like there's a compatibility issue with the `sliderInput` and touchscreens in the latest stable release (though you may be able to use the slider with the touchscreen itself). If you grab the dev version (`devtools::install_github('rstudio/shiny')`) it should resolve the problem.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/shiny-discuss/KBWNzdRVDs4